# SignalR gets Disconnected after 3 minutes and on reconnect after disconnect the process starts again from point zero

Tags: c#, signalr-hub

The scenario is i am **sending 1000+ emails**  using sendgrid api.
and i have used  **signalR**  for notifying the user how many emails have been delivered and how many has not while sending the emails.
After three minutes the signalr connection gets disconnected.
i get error Connection disconnected due to inactivity more than 30 sec.

i have tried to set keep-alive property null, and also for 5 days,
same for connection-timeout. when i set these properties i do not get the error message. But Connection gets disconnects and restarts also the process of sending the emails starts from point zero.

here is my code

```
$(function () {

        ///Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var progress = $.connection.progressHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        // Function To nitify the user of email state
        progress.client.AddProgress = function (message, percentage, delivered, error) {                
            ProgressBarModal("show", delivered, error, message);
            $("#ProgressMessage").css("width", percentage + "%");                
            $('#ProgressMessage').text(percentage + "%");
            if (percentage == "100%") {
                ProgressBarModal();
            }
        };

        $.connection.hub.start({ pingInterval: null }).done(function () {
            var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
        });

        $.connection.hub.connectionSlow(function () {
            console.log("connectionSlow");
        });

        $.connection.hub.reconnecting(function () {
            console.log("Reconnecting Hub ");
        });

        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {                
            if ($.connection.hub.lastError) {
                alert("Disconnected. Reason: " + $.connection.hub.lastError.message);
            }

            // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }, 6); 

        });
    });
```

hub Code

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public static void SendProgress(string progressMessage, int progressCount, int totalItems, int delivered, int error)
    {
        try
        {                                
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();

            //CALCULATING PERCENTAGE BASED ON THE PARAMETERS SENT
            var percentage = (progressCount * 100) / totalItems;

            progressMessage = "Processed Mails " + progressCount + " out of " + totalItems + ".";

            //PUSHING DATA TO ALL CLIENTS
            context.Clients.All.AddProgress(progressMessage, percentage.ToString(), delivered, error);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

and i call this in c# controller Action in for loop and the loop sleeps for 1 min after every 100 mails send irrespectively of email status.

```
ProgressModalUiUpdate(progressbarResult, campaignSessionid, errorCount, hubCount, totalNoOfMailsToBeSend);
```

can anyone help me solve the problem.

Comment: Could you work out what was the issue? I am seeing the same issue of disconnect at every 3 minutes.